# How to get value from config file and replace the value using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

i have a one config file which contain multiple rows.

file contain data like

```
<Configuration>
<servicemodel>
    <server version="9.5.0.0" modification="10">
    ...
    .
    </server>
</servicemodel>
</configuration>
```

so want to get the modification value and increment by one and update the config file.

i tried to get the all rows but unable to get and update specific value for modification.

Code which i have tried unable to get the value in targetnode

```
$file2Xml = [xml](Get-Content "D:\Tridion\Web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config")

# Locate target node
$targetNode = $file2Xml.SelectSingleNode("//server[@modification]")

Write-Host "value is----" $targetNode
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a Tridion question, but ala. I've done this in the past a little bit different:

```
# Define the location of web.config
$webconfigPath = "D:\Tridion\Web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config"

# Create new object of type xml
$doc = New-Object xml

# Load the xml into the xml-document (figure out if you have to use 'Convert-Path')
$doc.Load((Convert-Path $webconfigPath))

# Updated the modification attribute
$doc.configuration.servicemodel.server.modification = 10;

# Save and close
$doc.Save($webconfigPath)
```

Google is your friend here. Just google for 'Powershell edit xml' (and not Tridion ;) )